# Two files linked to one movie on plex

Tags: plex

I have two movie files, for different movies that have got attached to one movie. I have provided an image here

**How do I split these to map to two different movies?**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Name the files with the year of publication (according to the Plex naming conventions), like that:

Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 1 (2010).mkv

Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows Part 2 (2011).mkv

If that does not solve it, you may use the context menu options in Plex (when logged in as administrative user) and choose the "Split apart" option.

Comment: I have only one user, so assuming that is the admin user. Could you provide a screen shot containing the "Split apart" option.

Comment: renaming the files worked.

Comment: Looks like the files have to be in seperate folders for the split option to appear, like that:
Harry Potter Deathly Hallows Part 1/Deathly Hallows Part 1.mkv
Harry Potter Deathly Hallows Part 2/Deathly Hallows Part 2.mkv